# My sent email is contains the current computer date for no reason

Tags: windows-7, firefox, email, gmail, date

Everytime I tried to send an email through Gmail in Firefox, at the end of the e-mail, appears the current date in the format of

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM Timezone First Name Last Name Email Address:

So something like

[image]

And I'm not talking about the header

I tried to use Google Chrome and it's the same thing

Do anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I couldn't replicate this in Firefox or Chrome. Could you expand on the steps you took? Also perhaps look at any possible signatures you may have set up for Gmail. Finally, check in privacy/incognito/safe mode for the browser and see if this still happens.

Comment: Are you running any Gmail add-on tools? (Boomerang, Mailstrom, anything like that?)

Comment: Odd, I did not run any add-ons

Comment: This is an _attribution line_.  What M. Frank asks is important.  You need to tell answerers in your question exactly what actions you are taking in order to compose and to send mail.

Comment: i.e. [Gmail signatures](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8395?hl=en), [Firefox extensions (Add-ons)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-or-remove-add-ons), [Gmail labs](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29418?hl=en). Also, some anti-malware software may insert text towards the end, (it is usually configurable in the product).